# Beautifulsoup parse through poor tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My understanding is that regex is the poor man's approach to dealing with beautifulsoup, but I was wondering if it's my only option if there aren't well defined tags in the html I'm trying to parse?

I'm ultimately just trying to get some simple data from the html...but it's just in a series of tables that look like this:

```
<table width="733" border="0" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td align="right" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#29ff36">
<font size="-1" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
<strong>
PART CODE:
</strong>
</font>
</td>
<td align="left" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
<font size="-1" color="#7b1010" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
PART#  (//THIS IS WHAT I WANT)
</font>
</td>
<td>
</td>
```

Is there a good way to approach this without regex?

Thanks for the help guys. This site is incredible

OK:

There's about 15 of those tables, each has a label (such as Cost, Vendor, On-Hand) which sits in the first cell, and then the data that I actually want is always in the next cell over.

```
label = 'Price:'
rows = soup.findAll('tr')
for tr in rows:
  cols = tr.findAll('td')
  for td in cols:
    if td.find(text=True) == label:
      print td.find(text=True)
```

That works well enough to find the correct cell with the label in it... I basically just need to find the next cell over now I guess. The "next" command per the beautifulsoup documentation is not really accomplishing this though.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, you can use `BeautifulSoup`. But I don't suspect that's the answer you want. Can you clarify the question a bit?

Comment: What is unique about the data you want? Is it always in the second cell of the first row of the table? Does the text begin with some specific text each time? There no way to tell BeautifulSoup, or any other HTML parser what data to extract without that kind of information.

Comment: BeautifulSoup allows to retrieve set of tables and set of rows for each table in a few lines of code.  Getting "PART# (//THIS IS WHAT I WANT)" is pretty easy too.  Provide some sample which causes problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you provided isn't exactly clear, but here's a snippet that will retrieve the Part# from your example HTML source:

```
columns = soup.findAll('td')
for col in columns:
    try:
        part = col.find("font", {"color": "#7b1010"}).contents[0]
        print(part)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Thought I'd just store this into a list and then pull up the data from a standard list --only problem is there's a different number of tables each time... ie, sometimes part# sits in part[5], sometimes it's in part[9]

Is there a way I can specifically look for "PART CODE:" and then run this code?

Any tips on how to do this search

Comment: @Jen Scott The trick is to identify the smallest possible partition of the page that will contain all the data you'd need in order to parse correctly.

In this case, I'd suggest doing a soup.findAll() on the page tr elements, then a rows.findAll() on each tr to get the columns.  If both the PART CODE and PART # are present in a row, you know to save the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with `lxml` instead of `beautifulsoup`.  I switched over to using [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/dev/lxmlhtml.html) instead of `beautifulsoup` because of the [`cssselect()`](http://lxml.de/dev/cssselect.html) method.  It takes css rules just like you would use in a css file or jQuery.

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

raw_html_data = """ ... your html data here ... """

doc = fromstring(raw_html_data)
part_number = doc.cssselect('td[align=left] font')[0].text
# part_number.strip() # optionally strip leading and trailing whitespace
```

You can use [`pip`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) to install `lxml`.

```
$ pip install lxml
```

Silver platter solution:

```
# ... starting with doc from above
info = []
target_trs = doc.cssselect('table tr')  # tweak based on actual html
for tr in trs:
    target_cells = tr.cssselect('td font')
    label = target_cells[0].text.strip()
    data = target_cells[1].text.strip()
    info.append((label,data))
# now you have an array of (label,data) pairs in info
```

Comment: This isn't working. I'm guessing trs is supposed to be target_trs but I'm still getting an attribute error: nonetype object has no attribute 'strip' running this.

Comment: Yep, typo... s/target-trs/trs/.  Play with this in a console (python console or browser console with javascript) to get it right.  You really need to just start playing with this stuff and you will learn everything you need to figure things out using either beautifulsoup or lxml.  Your problem with NoneType sounds like your html is not formatted 100% consistently or maybe you need to try using something else to select the final target cells.  Test again on a smaller snippet of html to make sure it works and then test with the entire page's html.  Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

The lxml people claim to work well with malformed HTML.